# For Alexander, what were the incentives of expanding to the west vs to the east?

Tags: ancient-history, alexander-the-great

For Alexander, what were the incentives of expanding to the west vs to the east?

If Alexander would have decided to go westwards, would it be as successful and rewarding in comparison to his eastwards expansion.

Comment: Persia was in the east, why would he go west? The rest of the question appears to be a call for speculation.

Comment: @Semaphore : Yes, Why did he go east instead of west is the question. So Persia was all there was? nothing in the west? is there no difference between speculation and analysis of cost/benefits of historical events? Why he went east?

Comment: Alexander didn't just wake up one morning and decide to conquer the known world. He inherited his father's plans, years in the making, of invading Persia at the head of a Panhellenic alliance. Beyond them both is a legacy of *centuries* of Greco-Persian warfare, which gave Greee a banner of revenge. It was *not* a matter of "cost/benefit analysis", and any answer to what would have happened if he went west would be speculative.

Comment: I am not asking what would have happened if he went west. I am asking what were the pay offs of going east vs west. For example after finishing Persia, why continue with India and Egypt? and after that why not also expand westwards? was there nothing worth taking in the west?

Comment: Why would have anyone wanted to invade the poor West? Persia was rich, and the expedition of the 10.000 had shown that its army was ill-prepared against Greek/Macedonanian heavy infantry

Comment: Complete answer is a long story, but is easy to find. I vote to close as "trivia".

Comment: If Alexander The Great had chosen to go westward-(that is to say, an orchestration of campaigns which conquered and united the Greek city-states of Southern Italy, as well as, Sicily and other parts of the Western Mediterranean region), he and his Greek military would have encountered The Carthaginian Empire, which had dominated much of the Western Mediterranean region and nearly all of North Africa-(with the exceptions of Egypt & the North Libyan coast)  It is unknown as to whether or not Alexander and his Greek navy could have defeated.........

Comment: The might of the Carthaginian navy.  The Greeks had a very sophisticated and well trained navy, though the Carthaginians had an actual centuries long and very formidable naval based empire-(until the arrival or Rome).  Again, the results are just not known, which leads to endless conjecturing and speculating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The east had much more money than the west. To the east lay large empires with huge cities teaming with people and gold. All the major trade routes led to these places. Egypt itself produced vast amounts of grain. Italy's cities were much smaller and their economies relatively tiny. It would have cost far more to invade Italy than any amount that could be recovered there. [Douglas MacArthur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_MacArthur) famously said "Wars are caused by undefended wealth" and that is certainly the case here.

Livy nationalistically claimed that had Alexander invaded Italy, Rome, a tiny city state at the time, would have defeated him, a popular (with Romans), but not very realistic assessment. Strabo wrote that Alexander sent an embassy to Rome to complain about pirates operating out of Tuscany.

Comment: On the other hand, within a century Rome *had* held off the 'next Alexander', Pyrrhus of Epirus and within the next century after that had wiped out all of the Alexandrian successor states without breaking a sweat.

Answer (score 2):

It should also be noted that Macedonia was a relatively poor kingdom and the wealth of Persia was on a much higher level, especially for its aristocracy. The Greeks had been aware of this for at least two hundred years.  The Persians were also hated by most Greeks.  As it has been mentioned, it's easy to motivate people to go conquer a hated enemy AND get rich doing it. Conquering a relatively poor and ineffectual territory? Not so much.